# ¿Por qué cuando despliego en Netlify el archivo css me carga en blanco sin ningun estilo?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scss

- Este es el repo en GitHub : https://github.com/dcuevasdev/dcuevasdev_portfolio
- URL de la web: https://ivandanielcuevas.netlify.app/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Daniel, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar).

Comment: Hola gracias por respoder, lo que pasa es que no se cual sea el error como tal porque no se carga ningun archivo CSS, ni JS cuando hago el deploy en Netlify